# browserify-css with common modules css

Tags: css, browserify, bundling-and-minification

I use browserify-css with the project, which uses two libraries, which use another common library. All of these libraries have own `css` and after browserify with browserify-css transform, `css` from common library gets included in the final bundle multiple times. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases browserify-css always has same issues like this.
I prefer to use css-concatify better than that.